# Unity3dでのステージ作成をシーンごとに行うべきかどうか

Tags: unity3d

最近Unityで3dのPCでゲームを作り始めたのですが、
複数ステージを作成する場合にステージごとにシーンを作成するのか、
ステージのもとになるモデルデータをプレハブとして持ち、シーン切り替え時に
プレハブを切り替えるようにするかで悩んでいます。

以前2ｄでゲームを作成した際はメインゲーム画面にステージ用の背景とキャラを
ステージに応じて自動配置する手法だったためシーンは1つで済んでいましたが、
今回は３Dモデルを多用するためシーンごとに作成したほうがいいのか迷ったため
質問させていただきました。

またほかのゲームはどのようにステージを管理・作成しているかも気になるので
そちらもご回答いただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

厳密にはどっちでもいいです。
いろいろなサンプルゲームのソースを見る限りだと、
シーンごとにステージをわけていることが多いと思います。

私の場合、スマートフォン市場、Unity4初期の頃もあってシーンわけではなく、1シーン管理でプレハブまたはJsonデータを使ってそういったことを実現する実装をしています。

3Dを多用する～云々はさておき、3Dを使う、広いマップを使う、ということをするのであればまずどういった設計をするのか、というところからはじめて、どちらが自分にとってやりやすい設計なのか、という考え方のもとで選択したほうがよいかと思います。
結局のところ正解なんてありません。

個人的におすすめなのはとにかく完成品を作って、試行錯誤して自分が一番納得できる設計を探すことだと思います。